# Title case handling issue in C#

Tags: c#, .net, title-case

I have a requirement where every word in a string should be converted to title case but my exact convertion is as follows :

My present code is as follows :

```
row[col.ColumnName] = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Convert.ToString(row[col.ColumnName]).ToLower());
```

which converts "war and peace" to "War And Peace" but my requirement was  "War and Peace" where.

At present ToTitleCase function was not helpfull.

Please suggest any possible solution for me.

Thanks.

Comment: The is the expected result. For anything else, you'd have to write your own algorithm. See: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to write a function to scan the string passed for connecting words (and, or, of ), and capitalize everything else.  I am not aware of anything in .net to handle it otherwise.

Wrote this real quick, it is dirty but works.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class theclass
{
static void Main()
{
    string str1 = "war and peace";
    string str2 = "mr. popper's penguins";
    Console.WriteLine(Titlizing(str1));
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(Titlizing(str2));


}

public static string Titlizing( string toTitle )
{
    string[] dawords = toTitle.Split(' ');
    string output = "";
    TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US",false).TextInfo;

    foreach (string s in dawords)
    {

        switch(s)
        {
            case "and":
                output += ' '+ s;
                break;
            case "or":
                output += ' '+ s;           
                break;
            case "of":
                output += ' '+ s;
                break;
            default:
            {
                output += ' '+myTI.ToTitleCase(s);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
}
```

I received "War and Peace" when I passed war and peace.

Hope that helps.